# AngularJS: ng-switch-when with an OR

Tags: angularjs, ng-switch

Is it possible to have an OR in ng-switch-when?

```
<div ng-repeat="w in windows" ng-show="visibleWindowId == w.id" ng-switch="w.type">
    <div ng-switch-when="val1 **OR** val2">
        sup
    </div>
</div>
```

If not, how could the above be accomplished?

Thanks :)

Comment: did you try || ? val1||val2 , i guess it should work.

Comment: Needs an override , here's the detailed method : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17805636/how-can-i-use-ng-switch-to-satisfy-multiple-same-conditions/19146745#19146745

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`ngswitch` only allows you to compare a single condition.

I you are looking to test multiple conditions you can use `ng-if` available with [version 1.1.5](http://blog.angularjs.org/2013/05/angularjs-107-monochromatic-rainbow-and.html)

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16741949/ngif-and-ngswitch-angularjs)

*It is important to note that using `ng-if` and `ng-switch` [remove the element from the DOM](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngSwitch) structure, opposed to show and hide.*

*This is important when you traverse the DOM to find elements.*

Comment: Correct answer. But .. "This is important when you traverse the DOM to find elements." - Strange, I don't think I ever do this with Angular, after all, its not the angular way.

Comment: @Blowsie I really don't either (that is really the selling point of angular isn't it?).  But there is a chance someone might create a directive and need that functionality and I would rather people know and have an understanding of what they are implementing.

Comment: It's relevant when using CSS selectors like `+`, `:first-child`, `:empty` etc.

Answer (score 16):

This is now possible using `ng-switch-when-separator` which was added to Angular documentation in 1.5.10:

```
<div ng-repeat="w in windows" ng-show="visibleWindowId == w.id" ng-switch="w.type">
    <div ng-switch-when="val1|val2" ng-switch-when-separator="|">
        sup
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

This will work too

```html
<div ng-repeat="w in windows" ng-switch="w.type == 'val1' || w.type == 'val2'">
  <div ng-switch-when="true">
    sup
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems like an ngIf is more suitable here.

Answer (score 5):

I created a simple directive in place of `ngSwitchWhen` that allows you to specify multiple cases for a single tag. It also allows you to specify dynamic values instead of purely static values.

One caveat, it only evaluates the expression once upon compile time, so you must return the correct value immediately. For my purposes this was fine as I was wanting to use constants defined elsewhere in the application. It could probably be modified to dynamically re-evaluate the expressions but that would require more testing with `ngSwitch`.

I am use angular 1.3.15 but I ran a quick test with angular 1.4.7 and it worked fine there as well.

[Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/LD1ovMiVASsFoxOWBSDO?p=preview)

#### The Code

```
module.directive('jjSwitchWhen', function() {
    // Exact same definition as ngSwitchWhen except for the link fn
    return {
        // Same as ngSwitchWhen
        priority: 1200,
        transclude: 'element',
        require: '^ngSwitch',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl, $transclude) {
            var caseStms = scope.$eval(attrs.jjSwitchWhen);
            caseStms = angular.isArray(caseStms) ? caseStms : [caseStms];

            angular.forEach(caseStms, function(caseStm) {
                caseStm = '!' + caseStm;
                ctrl.cases[caseStm] = ctrl.cases[caseStm] || [];
                ctrl.cases[caseStm].push({ transclude: $transclude, element: element });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

#### Usage

Controller

```
  $scope.types = {
      audio: '.mp3', 
      video: ['.mp4', '.gif'],
      image: ['.jpg', '.png', '.gif'] // Can have multiple matching cases (.gif)
  };
```

Template

```
  <div ng-switch="mediaType">
    <div jj-switch-when="types.audio">Audio</div>

    <div jj-switch-when="types.video">Video</div>

    <div jj-switch-when="types.image">Image</div>

    <!-- Even works with ngSwitchWhen -->
    <div ng-switch-when=".docx">Document</div>

    <div ng-switch-default>Invalid Type</div>
  <div>
```

Comment: Very nice, i called it `ng-switch-multiple-when`

Answer (score 2):

You could use `ng-class` so that you can use `or` operator in your expression.
Also, angular-ui has `if` directive.