# ngIf and ngSwitch AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

What's practical difference between [`ngIf`](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.directive:ngIf) and `ngSwitch`? Both directives manipulate the DOM, but `ngSwitch` is more verbose. Is the typical case to just use `ngIf` unless you need something really big in which case use `ngSwitch`?

Is there a situation where `ngSwitch` and `ngIf` are not direct replacements? Or is their only practical difference the syntax?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[Michele Tilley's got it exactly right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16742553/1175496), I believe, particularly in pointing out the contrast with `ngShow`/`ngHide`. There's one additional difference to note: `ng-If` will detach and re-attach an element *in-place*. But `ng-Switch` has an outer containing element on which you declare the main directive and its condition: `ng-switch="expression"`. The conditional content within that outer element will be `append()`-ed as the *last child* of the outer element, thus changing its position relative to any non-conditional content within the outer element.

And, see [this CodePen](http://cdpn.io/GtsEb) for an interactive demo of all three, showing the differences in execution.

---

EDIT: This behavior changed in Angular 1.2. Elements are now left in place. The Codepen above mentions and demonstrates this, providing a link to a 1.08 Plunk that has sadly been wiped out...

Answer (score 41):

`ngIf` is basically a version of `ngSwitch` with a single condition. It's different from `ngShow` in that it removes the actual DOM element rather than simply hiding it. If you're using an `ngSwitch` with just a singly truthy condition check, then I believe `ngIf` will do the same thing.

Answer (score 7):

One more difference would be that ngIf and ngSwitch create new scopes, while ngShow/ngHide don't.

Comment: This is a useful comment, but in no way answers the actual question.

Answer (score 1):

You can think in ngIf/ngSwitch in the same way you do with if/switch when you are coding. Obviously they do almost the same thing, but there are cases that a ngIf is better and there are cases where nfSwitch is better.

Comment: For instance, `ngSwitch` is better if you have a few cases _and_ a default case that is essentially `!= any of the above`