# Different between *ngIf vs [ngSwitch] in Angular 2+

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if, ng-switch

What are the differences between `[ngSwitch]` and a bunch of `*ngIf`s. Any performance factors we should be concerned about?

***ngIf**

```
  <div *ngIf="day === 'MONDAY'">
     Keep calm and pretend it's not Monday.
  </div>
  ...
  <div *ngIf="day === 'FRIDAY'">
     Happy Friday!
  </div>
```

**[ngSwitch]**

```
<ng-container [ngSwitch]="day">

     <div *ngSwitchCase="'MONDAY'">
         Keep calm and pretend it's not Monday.
     </div>
     ...
     <div *ngSwitchCase="'FRIDAY'">
         Happy Friday!
     </div>

</ng-container>
```

Comment: https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/built-in-directives/ngif-and-ngswitch/

Comment: similar using angular js - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16741949/ngif-and-ngswitch-angularjs

Answer (score 11):

For `*ngIf`, every condition will be checked and the code inside the `true` condition will be executed.

For `[ngSwitch]`, only the code inside the specific case will be executed (using `break;`).

So, `[ngSwitch]` will be faster where there are multiple cases.

Answer (score 2):

**ngIf** is basically a version of **ngSwitch** with a single condition. It's different from ngShow in that it removes the actual DOM element rather than simply hiding it. If you're using an ngSwitch with just a singly truthy condition check, then I believe ngIf will do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

*ngIf works like if statement and ngSwitch (actually comprised of two directives, an attribute directive, and a structural directive) work as a switch statement in the DOM.

Knowing the difference between if-else statement and switch cases will help you understand further,
https://techdifferences.com/difference-between-if-else-and-switch.html