# How can I use ng-switch to satisfy multiple, same conditions?

Tags: angularjs

I want to create a piece of HTML with AngularJS based on the authentication status.

I use `ng-switch`.

The issue is that I want to have multiple hits on a single condition, but AngularJS only satifies the last condition met.

The HTML listens very close, because of Bootrap with fluent layout. The `span3` and `span9` must be directly below `row-fluid` container div, otherwise it will not float nicely. So I cannot introduce extra `ng-switch` divs to it...

```
<div class="row-fluid" ng-switch on="user.isAuthenticated">
<div class="span3" ng-switch-when="true"><div>
<div class="span9 spade-contentwrapper" ng-switch-when="true"><div>
<div class="spade-contentwrapper" ng-switch-when="false"><div>
<div>
```

See my simplified [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DrDelete/nnmh2/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular 1.1.5 supports `ng-if`. You can look at [that](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.directive%3angIf). Then you can have independent conditions.

Comment: Unfortunately 1.1.5 is an unstable version. Is it possible to have a workaround that works in 1.0.7 stable ?

Comment: ng-if was taken from angularui i believe. You have the source code for 1.1.5. Pull it out as source code if it does not have any dependency.

Comment: I fixed it with ng-show instead of ng-if or ui-if, and it works. When AngularJS 1.1.5 becomes stable (or promoted to stable), I'll replace the ng-show with the ng-if statements so DOM will not be poluted. Thx.

Comment: An example would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Someone overwrote the ngSwitchWhen Directive to include the option to allow || operators, you can find the original response here: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngSwitch by angabriel

```
config(function($routeProvider, $provide) {
/**
* overwrite angular's directive ngSwitchWhen
* can handle ng-switch-when="value1 || value2 || value3"
*/
    $provide.decorator('ngSwitchWhenDirective', function($delegate) {
    $delegate[0].compile = function(element, attrs, transclude) {
        return function(scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
          var subCases = [attrs.ngSwitchWhen];
          if(attrs.ngSwitchWhen && attrs.ngSwitchWhen.length > 0 && attrs.ngSwitchWhen.indexOf('||') != -1) {
          subCases = attrs.ngSwitchWhen.split('||');
        }
        var i=0;
        var casee;
        var len = subCases.length;
        while(i<len) {
            casee = $.trim(subCases[i++]);
            ctrl.cases['!' + casee] = (ctrl.cases['!' + casee] || []);
            ctrl.cases['!' + casee].push({ transclude: transclude, element: element });
        }
    }
    }
    return $delegate;
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you [Ty Danielson](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2661425/ty-danielson)
for posting the solution i found a few weeks ago. I'm glad when it helps others. Turns out it still works nicely with latest 1.2.0-rc.3. By the way: the inject of the $routeProvider is actually not needed, but i guess every angular app relies on it, so its more clear where this code has to go.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the ng-switch directive only supports multiple matches since version 1.1.3 of AngularJS.

See the [changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#features-2) and this [commit](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/0af172040e03811c59d01682968241e3df226774) as reference.