# AngularJs : how to use multiple condition inside ng-switch?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-switch

I have a div based on switch but in one particular case even when switch case will be true I need to display another link based on different condition. Can some one suggest me any ideas ?

```
  <div ng-switch="hasUrl">
    <a ng-switch-when="true && row.id.indexOf(:) < 0" href="{{url + row.id}}">
    {{getName(row)}}
    </a>
    <a ng-switch-default href=".......">
      {{getName(row)}}
    </a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ngswitch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch) only allows you to compare a **`single condition.`**

if you want to test multiple conditions you can use [**`ng-if`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)

If you still need to use multiple conditions, look at the answer with a directive.

[`AngularJS: ng-switch-when with an OR`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14492830/angularjs-ng-switch-when-with-an-or)

Answer (score 1):

You may need other tags such as `ng-show` and `ng-if`

Comment: Thanks. But can I use   <a ng-switch-when="row.id.indexOf(':') < -1 === true" href = "..." /> in the same switch ?